# Update query on sqlite3 not working through PHP PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am using sqlite and trying to connect to it through my PHP script.
The select query is working but the update query is not working
Please find below the code snippet

```
$dir = 'sqlite:/var/www/html/BMKAOAData.db';
$dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");

$query = 'update KAOAData set comments = :Comments where aptNo = :aptNo';
$stmt= $dbh->prepare($query);
if(!$stmt){
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}

$stmt->bindParam(':Comments',$myComments,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':aptNo',$myaptNo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
print "Updated $count rows\n";
```

I searched a lot for its solution and tried various methods but couldn't resolve it. Note that I have the database in the same directory of the script and I have given right permission to it and all its parent directory.
I am executing the same query in sqlite prompt and it is working fine.
Please help to resolve this.

Comment: check for errors via php's error reporting and PDO exceptions, then come back and tell us what they are. You won't get a magic answer here, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is the database autocommit set to false? In that case

```
$dbh->commit();
```

could solve your issue

Comment: Hi Flavio, not really. Infact commit would be required when it is set off and used in conjunction with beginTransaction().

Comment: Yes, that was my question: to check if the database autocommit is set to false.

Comment: Anyway if that is not the issue, may you check and eventually paste the log. 
What is the $count variable value after the update?